# Python, Selenium "'bool' object is not callable" Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to prepare a bot for a platform with using python and selenium. My codes are below. When I runned I saw a error like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\Python\eksi_01.py", line 76, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(recaptchaSolved.is_displayed())
  File "C:\Users\doguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

```
## necessary import codes
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import xlrd
import random

## random waiting time
random_Get_Time = random.randint(1,5)

## importing data file
data_File_Path = "C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/Python/DataFile.xls"

## targeting the data
dataFile = xlrd.open_workbook(data_File_Path)
accountInfo = dataFile.sheet_by_name("account_Ids_And_Passwords")
usernameCount = accountInfo.nrows
passwordCount = accountInfo.ncols
for curr_row in range(1, usernameCount):
    username = accountInfo.cell_value(1, 0)
    password = accountInfo.cell_value(1, 1)

## setting up recaptcha solver plugin to browser
recaptcha_Solver_Plugin_Path = "C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/Python/plugin.zip"

## adding recaptcha solver plugin to browser
recaptchaSolverAddOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
recaptchaSolverAddOptions.add_extension(recaptcha_Solver_Plugin_Path)

## browser driver code
chrome_Driver_Path = "C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/Python/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_Driver_Path, options=recaptchaSolverAddOptions)

## enter the browser
driver.get("**URL**")
time.sleep(random_Get_Time)

## fullscreen code
driver.maximize_window()

## filling account infos
login_Form_Username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
login_Form_Username.send_keys(username)
time.sleep(random_Get_Time)
login_Form_Password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
login_Form_Password.send_keys(password)

## waiting for captcha confirmation
recaptchaDisplayed = driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha')
if(recaptchaDisplayed.is_displayed()):
    recaptchaSolved = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Solved')
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(recaptchaSolved.is_displayed())
else:
    time.sleep(random_Get_Time)

## log in to platform
login_Button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn')
login_Button.click()
time.sleep(random_Get_Time)

## logout from driver
driver.quit()
```

How can I fix that?

What I'm trying to do is there is a Google Captcha confirmation on login page. If there isn't don't wait much. If there is, wait until recaptcha solver plugin fix it.

If I remove "## waiting for captcha confirmation" section and add time.sleep(110) it will solved. But I need to make that similar with human. I'm waiting for your helps.

Instead of

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(recaptchaSolved.is_displayed())
```

I tried that

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Solved')]")))
```

But it gave an error again. Like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doguk\Desktop\Python\eksi_01.py", line 75, in <module>
    recaptchaSolved = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Solved')
  File "C:\Users\doguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 462, in find_element_by_partial_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Users\doguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\doguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\doguk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Solved"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

Comment: `recaptchaSolved.is_displayed()` probably returns `bool` value

Comment: Does my answer resolve your problem?